# How to: Use JQuery to fetch and update ONLY the following classes under a button living in one of those classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working fiddle is  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/ptpyp66L/) and I'm trying to show/hide parent/child nodes.

Sample structure related to the question (conceptually similar to the fiddle)

```
    <div class="card LevelOne">
    <button></button>
</div>

<div class="card LevelTwo">
    <button></button>
</div>

<div class="card LevelThree">
    <button></button>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is. if I click on a button under class level one, hide level two and there. If I click on a button under class two, only hide three. Kind of like that structural parent/child hide capability. what's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you change the markup? I mean you looking for general solution or solution only for that markup?

Comment: Thanks Mehdi. My main markup is in fiddle link. However, if someone can help me conceptually that's ok too. Hope I'm not making answering this harder than it should be. New to this, let me know bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `nextAll()`

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll(".card").toggle()
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll(".card").toggle();
})
```

```css
.card
{
   margin:20px;
   padding:10px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card LevelOne">
  <button>Button1 For toggle below 2</button>
</div>

<div class="card LevelTwo">
  <button>Button2 For toggle below 1</button>
</div>

<div class="card LevelThree">
  <button>Button3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, Thumps Up!

Comment: Damn. succinct! Love it, let me see how I can use it on my JSFiddle. Thanks, bro!

Comment: Btw, what do you do if you structure is nested...

https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/euyef1kL/

Comment: Nvm, here's an answer to that (in case anyone lands here by search).. the parents() selector. Just ran into this cheatsheet- https://oscarotero.com/jquery/ amazing resource.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Dude! You are my hero for today. Thanks. I'll keep you posted on the end result. Here is recent progress with minor changes- https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/ptpyp66L/11/